# How do I set a card in trello to be archived using httppost?

Tags: trello, roblox

I would like to be able to archive (or delete) a card in trello, but using httppost.
I'm using ROBLOX, on their HTTPService.
This is something I came up with, but it does not seem to work.

```
function DeleteCard(cardid)
    local url
    local cardi = tostring(cardid)
    url="https://api.trello.com/1/cards/"..cardi.."/actions"..getAddon() -- getAddon() is a function that returns the key to allow me to make modifications on the board. This works, I'm able to create lists/cards fine.
    local dat = {
    closed=true
    }
    local data = HS:JSONEncode(dat)
    local delc = HS:PostAsync(url,data)
    print(tostring(delc))
end
```

I have tried many different methods of doing this, I just can't seem to set any actions.
It usually responds with either a 404, or a 400. The cardid is gathered properly with this function:

```
function GetCardID(name,boardid)
    local url
    url="https://api.trello.com/1/boards/"..boardid.."/cards"..getAddon()
    local tab=HS:GetAsync(url,true)
    local tabl=HS:JSONDecode(tab)
    for k,ta in pairs(tabl) do
        for p,t in pairs(ta) do
            if p=="name" and t==name then
                return ta.id
            end
        end
    end
end
```

It does get the card id correctly, I've tested.

I've looked up https://trello.com/docs/api/card/ and tried my best to use these resources but I just cannot understand how to call a "DELETE", or how to set the "actions" to archive.

Comment: You're using `PostAsync`, which means to make a POST request.  Maybe there's something like `DeleteAsync` to make a DELETE request?

Answer (score 1):

[The only metods that roblox currently allows are GET and POST.](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/HttpService#YieldFunctionsmemberhiddenYieldFunctions_.5Btoggle.5D)
This is usually enough, however in this case it means that you can't use any of the Trello API calls that uses PUT and DELETE.

And in your case the [deletion of a card requires the DELETE method](https://trello.com/docs/api/card/index.html#delete-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink) and the [archiving of a card requires the PUT method](https://trello.com/docs/api/card/index.html#put-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink-closed).

However, this does not mean that you are out of luck. You can have a own server (or a third-party) get normal POST requests from ROBLOX and send them to Trello using the correct method.